# cellSelectionModel is not getting information when another cell from the same row is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with cellSelectionModel. its not getting information when another cell from the same row is selected
example if I select 11, it returns information, but if I select 12 after that i wont return me anything, do you know anyway to correct this?

Example Code:

```
public class TableListener {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTable table;

        String[] columnTitles = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        Object[][] rowData = { { "11", "12", "13", "14" }, { "21", "22", "23", "24" },
                { "31", "32", "33", "34" }, { "41", "42", "44", "44" } };

        table = new JTable(rowData, columnTitles);

        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                String selectedData = null;

                int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();
                int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();

                for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) {
                        selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
            }

        });

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another listener:

```
table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
...
```

where the

```
public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
```

is relevant for you.